# Unity Animation Transitions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a separate script that handles my player animations; it doesn't have any issues within that script. The reason I know is because it works for my player's walk, jump, and crouch animations. However, the issue arises when the player presses the left mouse click to attack. It transitions for a split second and then resumes the player's walk, idle, jump, or crouch animation. In the player input function, I have a bool that checks if I'm attacking, and above it, I have an On Enabled function that enables my Input Actions Map for the player inputs.

```
        // Player Input
        private void CheckCombatInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
        {
            if (context.performed)
                isAttacking = true;
        }

        // Player Move 
        public void PlayerMove()
        {
            bool isWalking = false;
            if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0)
            {
                Flip();
            }
            else if (!isFacingRight && horizontal > 0)
            {
                Flip();
            }

            moveSpeed = playerMovementForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            if (isCrouching)
            {
                moveSpeed *= crouchSpeedMultiplier;
            }

            rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
            if (isGrounded && !jump && !isCrouching && !isAttacking)
            {
                isWalking = Mathf.Abs(horizontal) > 0;
                PlayerAnimator.Instance.ChangeAnimationState(isWalking ? PlayerAnimator.Player_Walk                               :               PlayerAnimator.Player_Idle);
            }
        }

        // Player Attack
        private void PlayerAttacks()
        {
            if (isAttacking)
            {
                canFlip = false;
                PlayerAnimator.Instance.ChangeAnimationState(PlayerAnimator.Player_Attack);
                isAttacking = false;
            }
            else
            {
                canFlip = true;
                isAttacking = false;
            }
        }
```

I tried making a finite State Machine it is still to complicated for me to implement for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think, to fix this issue, you can try following steps in your script:

1. Delay Resetting `isAttacking:` Move `isAttacking = false;` to the end of the attack animation instead of immediately after setting the attack state. This can be done using an Animation Event. (I will explain with details if you need with comment)
2. Check Animator Transitions: Please ensure that Animator transitions from the attack animation back to other states(like idle or walk) don't happen too quickly. Adjust the conditions and exit times in the Animator to allow the full attack animation to play.
3. Use Animation Layers: Place the attack animation on a separate layer in the Animator and set its priority higher. This allows the attack animation to play fully even if other animations are triggered.

Hope you have a good result with this.

Answer (score 0):

I find that sometimes using "flags"; e.g. "isMoving" to maintain state is difficult. Sometimes, it's useful to examine it from another aspect. E.g. if velocity > 0, it's obviously moving and a better indicator than using a flag. "Fighting" is usually the result of a collision; implying no forward movement and "in contact" and "facing" an enemy ("close combat"). If it was rear contact; you were attacked (surprised) from the rear (or flank) for "extra damage".